# ggscatter function not found in R

Tags: r

after installing ggpubr in R-Studio --`install.packages("ggpubr")` and activating it in the library `library(ggpubr)`, running the code below is giving me the following response: `'could not find function "ggscatter"`. kindly assist how I can overcome this.

***code*** -----

```
ggscatter(wbdata, x = "GDP_growth", y = "oda", add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE, cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson", xlab = "GDP GROWTH (%)", ylab= "Oversees Development Assistance")
```

Comment: Check this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/299)

Comment: What if you use `ggpubr::ggscatter(wbdata, x = "GDP_growth", ...)`?